Почему майнкрафт не вылетает, если мир состоит из миллионов объектов?
Мир состоит из блоков. Каждый блок это ведь отдельный элемент? Тогда почему майнкрафт не вылетает, если мир состоит из миллионов объектов? Причем если все блоки заменить сущностями, то майнкрафт вылетит очень даже скоро. А ещё установка и ломание блока не зависит от пинга и ТПС сервера/мира. Что за дикая оптимизация у блоков? Почему это так работает?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Вы же не думаете, что все блоки мира Майнкрафт подгружает в оперативную память? В настройках там даже есть опция — на какую дистанцию отображать блоки.

Не все объекты одинаково сложны или просты.. и даже не всё есть объект..

@Глеб беглый расчёт на калькуляторе показывает, что даже с дистанцией 16 чанков в видимом радиусе получается около сотни миллионов блоков (с учётом блоков воздуха, ведь факт наличия воздуха тоже нужно хранить в памяти), так что дистанция мало что объясняет

@andreymal, там радиус применения порядка 8 блоков, а то и 6. Остальные видны только по поверхности, так что в куб возводить не надо. И блоков воздуха там нет...

@Глеб чтобы сгенерировать поверхность, нужно прочитать информацию из блоков - в том числе блоков воздуха, ведь игра должна откуда-то узнать, что в таком-то месте рисовать ничего не надо, так что утверждение "блоков воздуха там нет" это чушь

@Глеб и кстати блоки хранят ещё освещение - и даже у блоков воздуха может быть разное освещение (например, в зависимости от расстояния до факела в пещере), а от освещения воздуха зависит некоторая игровая логика вроде спаунера мобов (он спаунит мобов именно в воздухе), так что это всё тоже придётся хранить

@andreymal, действительно, об этом я как-то не подумал...
